# count elements before last spacebars

Tags: prolog

I want to count the number of elements before last spacebars.
For example, I have a list `[a,b,_,_,f,g,h,_,_,_]` and the final result would
`X=3`.

```
last_word(String, Word) :-
  last_word(String, [], Word).
last_word([], Word, Word) :- !.
last_word([' '|TailString], _, Word) :-
  !, last_word(TailString, [], Word).
last_word([Char|TailString], Buff, Word) :-
  last_word(TailString, [Char|Buff], Word).

dellast([_],[]) :- !.
dellast([X|T],[X|Y]) :- dellast(T,Y).

num([],0).
num([_|L],N) :- num(L,N1),N is N1+1.

count(L,N) :-
    last(L,Elem),
    Elem=' ',
    dellast(L,D),
    last_word(D,W),
    num(W,N), !.
count(L,N) :-
    last_word(L,W),
    num(W,N), !.
```

Comment: `_` are not "spacebars". They are anonymous variables, and they will unify with any prolog term whether that term is a variable or not.

Comment: I think they are supposed to be space characters, not underscore.

Comment: @TomasBy it's totally speculative at this point.

Comment: @lurker Hmm, yes, but also hard to see any other explanation...

Comment: @TomasBy yes, probably so. I was fixated on the example list.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that what you want is this:

```
?- count([a,b,' ',' ',f,g,h,' ',' ',' '],N).
N = 3
```

There are various problems in your code. It is better to use if-then-else than speculative cuts. You need recursion on the top-level also.

In the code below, `N` is the number of characters in the last word (separated by spaces), and `T` is the number in the current word so far. Initially they are both zero.

```
count(L,N) :-
  count(L,0,0,N).

count([C|L],T0,N0,N) :-
  ( C = ' ' ->
    ( T0 = 0 ->
      N1 = N0, T1 = 0
    ; N1 = T0, T1 = 0 )
  ; T1 is T0 + 1, N1 = N0 ),
  count(L,T1,N1,N).
count([],_,N,N).
```

So for each character, there are three cases:

- Not space: `T` plus one
- First space after word (`T` non-zero): set `N` to `T`
- Space & no current word: nothing

Addition: this may not be what you want for the situation when the list ends with a character, but then you can add an if-then-else in the base case also.